# Autodetect a value type in a string in order to consider that an URL, e-mail address, 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, input

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to show URLs and e-mail addresses as links in a view. I retrieve the URL and the e-mail address information as typed by a user in a form input text field, so I will need to use a regular expression...

**How can I do?**

---

**BTW**:

From [here](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls) I have the following regexp:

```
(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))
```

When I try to state the above regexp in my class I have a trouble because there is an error in the `reg_url` declariation:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def check
    reg_url = (?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))
    ...
  end

end
```

Maybe, to solve this problem I have to insert at the end of bottom some other chars (example '\', '/', ...)...

Comment: Just as a FYI, if you weren't using Rails, you could use URI's [`URI::extract`](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/uri/1.9.2/URI#extract-class_method) method to identify the URLs, then iterate over them and `gsub` the links.

Comment: In Ruby, the correct syntax for writing a regular expression would be:  `regexp = /[0-9]/` or `regexp = Regexp.new('[0-9]')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then in a string you wish to  turn all the links and email addresses into anchor tags?

If so, then you should try the [auto_link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html) method.

Usage:

```
auto_link("Go to http://www.rubyonrails.org and say hello to david@loudthinking.com")
# => "Go to <a href=\"http://www.rubyonrails.org\">http://www.rubyonrails.org</a> and
#     say hello to <a href=\"mailto:david@loudthinking.com\">david@loudthinking.com</a>"
```

You may need to include the keyword "raw" before the auto_link call if the html appears escaped upon output.